# how to customize the response(add CaseNumber fields) of the http POST method?

Tags: webservices, apexrest, rest-service

How to get the CaseNumber field in the response of the http POST method, please help

**Code:**

```
 @HttpPost
    global static string dopost() {        
              RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
              RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
              Case tkt= (Case)JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(),Case.class);
              system.debug(tkt);
              try {              
                insert tkt;
              }
              catch(DmlException e) {
             return 'The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage();
        }              
              return JSON.serialize(tkt); 
    }
```

**Response :**

```
"{\"attributes\":
{\"type\":\"Case\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Case/5002800000S
zQ7QAAV\"},\"Status\":\"New\",\"Origin\":\"Phone\",\"Id\":\"5002800000SzQ7Q
AAV\",\"Subject\":\"New Case 001\",\"Reason\":\"Deviation\"}"
```

Comment: As long as you do not share  your code snippet it will be hard for anyone to help you

Comment: Added @Mohith Shrivastava

Comment: Are we able to remove the escape character "\" from the Response : "{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Case\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Case/5002800000SziK7AAJ\"},\"Id\":\"5002800000SziK7AAJ\",\"CaseNumber\":\"00001077\",\"Subject\":\"aslkdjfkjsd323232\",\"Status\":\"New\",\"Reason\":\"Deviation\",\"Origin\":\"Phone\"}"

Comment: If you follow second approach of returning case instead of string ,the escape character won't appesr

Comment: Am getting this error : Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'dopost' at line 14 column 23, when i tried with the 2nd code.

Comment: Just corrected some typo .Try now and if it answers please close the thread .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to query back the Case Number and return the object like below

```
@HttpPost
global static string dopost() {        
          RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
          RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
          Case tkt= (Case)JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(),Case.class);
          system.debug(tkt);
          try {              
            insert tkt;
          }
          catch(DmlException e) {
         return 'The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage();
    }       
        Case insertedCase = [Select Id,CaseNumber,Phone,Id,Status,Subject from Case Where Id =:tkt.Id];       
          return JSON.serialize(insertedCase); 
}
```

Also on another note ,you do not have to return a string ,instead you can make the return object as Case and platform will automatically take care of deserialising it for you

```
@HttpPost
global static Case  dopost() {        
          RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
          RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
          Case tkt= (Case)JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(),Case.class);
          system.debug(tkt);
          try {              
            insert tkt;
          }
          catch(DmlException e) {
         return 'The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage();
    }       
        Case insertedCase = [Select Id,CaseNumber,Phone,Id,Status,Subject from Case Where Id =:tkt.Id];       
          return insertedCase; 
}
```

Comment: No need for the temporary: `return [SELECT CaseNumber... FROM Case WHERE Id = :tck.Id];` works just as well.

Comment: :@Mohith Shrivastava, @sfdcfox : Are we able to remove the escape character "\" from the Response : "{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Case\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Case/5002800000SziK7AAJ\"},\"Id\":\"5002800000SziK7AAJ\",\"CaseNumber\":\"00001077\",\"Subject\":\"aslkdjfkjsd323232\",\"Status\":\"New\",\"Reason\":\"Deviation\",\"Origin\":\"Phone\"}"